Is xinetd necessary? How to detect actual use on a running server?
I have "inherited" a CentOS 7 server on which xinetd is automatically started at boot.
My task is to harden that server.  Therefore I am wondering whether I can disable the xinetd service.  However, this is a production machine which limits my freedom to try out things.  I might break something while trying but I should not.
So: How can I detect whether the xinetd is necessary?  Which other daemons/services are configured to be started by it (I suppose that's easy, look at /etc/xinetd.d files)?  Which of these have ever been started and are actively used / needed?
The files in /etc/xinetd.d might just be historical or from OS packages so these may not reflect needed services.  Nevertheless, here is a listing of that directory:
root@server.example.org:/root
-> ll /etc/xinetd.d/
total 52
-rw-------. 1 root root 1157 Apr  1  2020 chargen-dgram
-rw-------. 1 root root 1159 Apr  1  2020 chargen-stream
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2256 Aug  1  2018 check_mk
-rw-------. 1 root root 1157 Apr  1  2020 daytime-dgram
-rw-------. 1 root root 1159 Apr  1  2020 daytime-stream
-rw-------. 1 root root 1157 Apr  1  2020 discard-dgram
-rw-------. 1 root root 1159 Apr  1  2020 discard-stream
-rw-------. 1 root root 1148 Apr  1  2020 echo-dgram
-rw-------. 1 root root 1150 Apr  1  2020 echo-stream
-rw-------. 1 root root 1212 Apr  1  2020 tcpmux-server
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  518 Apr 11  2018 tftp
-rw-------. 1 root root 1149 Apr  1  2020 time-dgram
-rw-------. 1 root root 1150 Apr  1  2020 time-stream

PS: I know, at some point I will have to upgrade the OS itself but first things first.
Additional info: The server is serving home directories to a couple of clients by NFS, acts as a router for these and forwards active directory (AD) requests.  In fact, the AD functionality is the main reason I am unsure what is needed because I have yet to understand the AD communication protocol (and client/proxy/routing prerequisites).
Which services might xinetd be configured for?  Perhaps this output helps?
root@server.example.org:/root
-> netstat -tulpan | grep xinet
Exit 1
root@server.example.org:/root
-> lsof -c xinetd -ai
Exit 1

None?  I believe I have had processes not showing up in netstat and still react to incoming requests, perhaps by systemd or (x)inetd.
Let's ask /proc:
root@server.example.org:/root
-> cat /proc/`pidof xinetd`/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 0100007F:0019 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 36323 1 ffff9012125b07c0 100 0 0 10 0                     
   1: 00000000:007A 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 36262 1 ffff9012125b0000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   2: 00000000:199C 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 23844 1 ffff90125ca70000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   3: 00000000:A7E1 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 34529 1 ffff901211c58f80 100 0 0 10 0                     
   4: 00000000:0801 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 34515 1 ffff901211c587c0 100 0 0 10 0                     
   5: 00000000:006F 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 28319 1 ffff90125d6b0000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   6: 00000000:4E50 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 18419 1 ffff901212658000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   7: 00000000:EB51 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    29        0 34497 1 ffff901211c58000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   8: A13B2BAD:007A 8AB45373:AD92 01 00000000:00000000 02:0009786D 00000000     0        0 70547 3 ffff901211c5ec80 23 4 29 10 -1                    
root@server.example.org:/root
-> cat /proc/`pidof xinetd`/net/udp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
  143: 00000000:0043 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 29194 2 ffff90125f4f9100 0         
  144: 00000000:0044 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 36283 2 ffff90125a9a8000 0         
  144: 00000000:0044 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 37049 2 ffff901252cc8000 0         
  145: 00000000:0045 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 23877 2 ffff90125b659100 0         
  187: 00000000:006F 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 28317 2 ffff90125b118880 0         
  199: 00000000:007B 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 28979 2 ffff90125f4f8cc0 0         
  399: 0100007F:0143 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 28977 2 ffff90125f4f8880 0         
  779: 0100007F:02BF 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 34483 2 ffff900a63b51100 0         
  934: 00000000:035A 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 28318 2 ffff90125b118cc0 0         
 2125: 00000000:0801 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 34525 2 ffff900a63b50440 0         
 3740: 00000000:4E50 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 18417 2 ffff9012510e8440 0         
 8222: 00000000:DFD2 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 34528 2 ffff900a63b50880 0         
 8548: 00000000:2118 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 36299 2 ffff90125a9a8440 0         
 9933: 00000000:E681 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000    29        0 34494 2 ffff900a63b50000 0         

So, there are actually many ports it listens to?
Now chkconfig output:
root@server.example.org:/root
-> chkconfig --list |& awk '/xinetd based services/,/""/'
xinetd based services:
    chargen-dgram:  off
    chargen-stream: off
    check_mk:       on
    daytime-dgram:  off
    daytime-stream: off
    discard-dgram:  off
    discard-stream: off
    echo-dgram:     off
    echo-stream:    off
    tcpmux-server:  off
    tftp:           off
    time-dgram:     off
    time-stream:    off


A server ? A server of what ? What is served to what ? Moreover, in the prospect of "hardening", what makes you think disabling xinetd belongs to the "first things first" ?

Which of those services are enabled? What port is xinetd actually listening on (sudo lsof -c xinetd -ai). Does the firewall let connections through to those? Do logs show evidence of them being used? Note that nowadays, xinetd is superseded with systemd which can do the same thing in a more integrated way to the rest of the system.

In a more general way xinetd is the eXtended InterNET services Daemon.  It is a Super Service Daemon in that it controls all Internet Traffic coming into and going out of your server for monitored services that have been setup, i.e. FTP, SSH, Apache, etc, the reason it's called a Super Service is because all the protocols I listed can be configured and run from it, whereas systemd uses one service per application/protocol.  If you turn of xinetd, you will disable those services. To replace them, you must find the systemd replacement

@MC68020 Added info about the server purpose. By "first things first" in this case I just mean, reduce attack surface of running system by disabling services that are not needed (etc.), before upgrading to RL/AL 9 which I do not have time for right now.

Fair enough. Could you please post the ouput of chkconfig -list | awk '/xinetd based services/,/""/' ? (ran as root)

@MC68020 I have added the info. It lists check_mk only. However, /proc seems to suggest it is listening to a range of other ports, too. Can we tell which service potentially started by xinetd is configured to start and has actually been started within the last $n days?

OK, I'll try to write some more detailed answer.

@MC68020 Looking forward to reading it :-)
